# Prevent page scroll while the Bootstrap Modal is open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

How to prevent the page scroll while the Bootstrap Modal Dialog is open?

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button id="fechar" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">Fechar</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Bootstrap 3 should disable scroll on the modal be default with `overflow-x: hidden;` on the `.modal-open` class but I have also found that it doesn't work in some instances.